# Search against property in JSON object using MySQL 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

**Long story short:** I'm using MySQL 5.6 (at the moment, it's impossible to update to newer version and use improved JSON capabilities), and I have a column where JSON is stored.

Sample JSON objects stored in database:

```
-- Row #1 (`options` column)
{"name": "Test", "description": "Some description", "type": "post", "scheduled": true, "deleted": false, "timestamp": "1482263883"}

-- Row #2 (`options` column)
{"name": "", "description": "Some description test", "type": "post", "scheduled": true, "deleted": false, "timestamp": "1482263883"}
```

**The problem:** I want to be able to search over the records against `name` property stored in my JSON object.

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE ((`options` LIKE '%"name":"%Test%"%'))
```

The query above works fine, but sometimes it may return false positives (e.g. the second row will be returned as well as it contains "test" string in `description` property).

Some notes:

1. The object stored in `options` column is exactly the same for each row, e.g. `name` property is located at first position for each record.

Comment: Well, with the current implementation, it is not possible. You need to have the latest one to search only within the name.

Comment: The second row doesn't return because it has `test` in the description field, it returns because it also has the `name` of `test`. Of course both rows with that have the same value will be returned.

Comment: what do you want the search to return? the first and second rows should match as per the example as they have `"name": "Test"`.

Comment: Sorry, the question has been updated (now the `name` property in second row is empty, but it will be returned when query is executed).

Comment: try this : **SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE ((`options` LIKE '%"name": "Test%"%'))**

Comment: Your only other option then is to use a regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression instead of `LIKE`. This allows you to use a pattern that won't go across string boundaries, unlike the `%` wildcard in `LIKE`

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE options REGEXP '"name": *"[^"]*Test'
```

However, instead of the false positive you got, this could produce a false negative if a row contains:

```
"name": "This is a \"quoted\" Test"
```

because `[^"]*` will not go across the escaped quotes.

There might be some way to refine the regexp to allow for this, but it won't be simple.

Comment: i think `options regexp binary '"name":[[:space:]]"Test"'` would be enough and it handles case-sensitivity as well.

Comment: His original query has `"%Test%"`, so I thought he wanted to find a name that contains `Test` anywhere in it, not where it's an exact match. Because if that's what he wants he could just use `LIKE '%"name": "Test"%'` and he wouldn't get false positives.